# What color scheme is used for the code examples on o'reilly atlas site?

Tags: vim, colors, gvim

I would really like know what colorscheme this is, and if it is already available for vim.
The screengrab is taken from the O'Reilly Atlas site. [Link](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000393/ch01.html#_problem_5) to the actual site with more code examples.

[image: screen grab from atlas]

Answer (score 3):

That document appears to be created with the [DocBook](http://www.docbook.org/) documentation system, using [O'Reilly's own custom colorscheme](http://dwn0odqttrkhc.cloudfront.net/assets/book-e6243cc4cc3595e325ee635b31c10604.css).

I would say that your chances of finding a Vim colorscheme based on that style are very close to zero but you can always use their colors as a basis for your own colorscheme.

[The DocBook wiki](http://wiki.docbook.org/) may have useful customizing resources but I can't reach it at the moment, maybe you will be luckier than me.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they're using a custom scheme (evidenced by the bolding and `self` being highlighted differently), but you can find similar dark schemes with low-intensity colors in the [Vim Colorscheme Gallery](http://cocopon.me/app/vim-color-gallery/).